# CSS animation to make div appear smoothly from bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to make a `div` appear smoothly as shown in the GIF below. I assume this can be done using CSS animation but I have never worked on CSS animation before.

How to achieve it using CSS animation?

```css
body {
background:red;
}

.container  {
background:white;
padding:20px;
position: absolute;
bottom:20px;
left:45%;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
This is magic!
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, this animation can be done with CSS, using `@keyframes` for example, like below. To close it, add a button in it, with an event listener with JavaScript.

```css
@keyframes smooth-appear {
  to{
    bottom: 20px;
    opacity:1;
  }
}
.container {
  background: gray;
  color:white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  opacity:0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: smooth-appear 1s ease forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is magic!
</div>
```

Comment: body {overflow: hidden} ?

Comment: @VXp you are right, it does create a scroll bar. Your solution could work but then he should remove `overflow: hidden` to be able to scroll again. `position: fixed` would solve the issue more simply. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the code snippet you need to create an animation using the `keyframes` query and put the changing properties (the `position` in this case) into it.

Next use the `animation` property on the animated element.

```css
body {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes animation {
  from {
    bottom: -60px
  }
  to {
    bottom: 20px)
  }
}

.container {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
  animation: 2s animation;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  This is magic!
</div>
```

Comment: body {overflow: hidden} ? + not centered

Comment: Why would i use overflow hidden for body, there are no elements to overflow it. Regarding the centering i was only using the provided example I think the op can refer to the 11 ways to center a div article for that :) Edit: nevermind you're right about overflow but I got beat to an answer anyway